# Unable to add custom Activities to VS 2012 Workflow

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity

I've created and built a Workflow Activity Library project in Visual Studio 2012, and created a HelloWorld.xaml activity as follows:

[image: Activity that prints "Hello World!"]

Pretty basic, no frills. However, I can't seem to add this activity to a workflow template that I've copied. The Activity shows up in the Toolbox just fine, but when I try to drag it into the designer in an appropriate spot on the diagram the mouse cursor changes to the standard "disallowed" circle-with-a-line image and the activity isn't placed.

Is there something I'm fundamentally missing here? My understanding is that any activity in the Toolbox should be able to be dragged & dropped into the designer.

Comment: How did you add it to the toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

Make shure you have a reference to the project of the activity you want to add to your workflow.